# Yii2: how to login at frontend and backend in different db tables?

Tags: php, mysql, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

In yii2 advanced template there is already user registration with mysql. When I register it inserts in `users` new record. Wherever I am in `/frontend` or `/backend`, I can login via `users`.

I want to create new table `admins` for only admins. But how to tell yii2 to check `admins` instead `users` in `/backend`?

Answer (score 5):

You can set up different identityClass in backend / frontend configs.

In backend config - you have to reset your user component like this:

```
'user' => [
    'class' => 'yii\web\User', // basic class
    'identityClass' => 'common\models\Admin', // your admin model
    'enableAutoLogin' => true,
    'loginUrl' => '/admin/backend/login',
],
```

Set up your identity class like this:

```
class Admin extends ActiveRecord implements IdentityInterface
```